# Table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it/ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

The following is my trigger, which I am having a hard time implementing. It creates the trigger but has an error after I make a change on a price. The following trigger is to add a row to the DAYCARE_PRICE table when the table DAYCARE has a price change(update) on any of its rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER daycare_price_history_trg
BEFORE UPDATE ON DAYCARE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.price != :OLD.price THEN 
        INSERT INTO DAYCARE_PRICE(daycare_id, old_price, new_price, date_of_change)
        SELECT daycare_id, :NEW.price, :OLD.price, SYSDATE
        FROM DAYCARE;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Short answer: You can't select from the same row in DAYCARE that's being updated. Use NEW/OLD instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `VALUES` clause instead of selecting from the table (The Trigger Owner) for Insert.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER daycare_price_history_trg BEFORE
     UPDATE ON daycare
     FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF
          :new.price !=:old.price
     THEN
          INSERT INTO daycare_price (
               daycare_id,
               old_price,
               new_price,
               date_of_change
          ) VALUES (
               :new.daycare_id,
               :old.price,
               :new.price,
               SYSDATE
          );
     END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: This doesn't work... I get these errors: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: @MMC : You've made some mistake while copying and rewriting your actual code. Given your table definition of `DAYCARE_PRICE`,  this should work. It seems you have not specified the `:new` keyword where it is required (daycare_id ) or something? Check it thoroughly.

Comment: I tried copying your command exacly. Also, I do want to point out that daycare_id is not a new one; it should remain the same one being called from the daycare table.

Comment: You'd better do these things in a "AFTER" trigger: :new and :old values in "before" triggers can be altered by other "before" triggers... If there was another "before" trigger doing something like ":new.new_price := round(:new_price)", and this other trigger gets run after yours, you would log the wrong values.  After triggers, instead, get run when the data has been already written and is definitive.

Comment: @MMC : That does not mean you should directly use the column name `daycare_id`  without the `:NEW` or `:OLD` qualifiers in the `INSERT`, which   is the reason for the error. Try using `:OLD.daycare_id` instead of `:NEW`, if you do want it to remain the same